# Importing fontawesome.js with webpack gives CSP violation

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, inline, content-security-policy

I am using fontawesome in in my project and I am trying to add them to the project via webpack.

I have addad `import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome.js'` into my app.js and have added `@import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';` to my main.css file.

However, when I am loading my app in the borwser, I am getting the following CSP violation error.

```
Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ixVUGs3ai0rMA0pgIVBN0KVlYbQip7/5SGmnUwJPNqE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

The error points to the following section of code that is coming from [fontawesome.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/fontawesome.js)

```
function insertCss(css) {
    if (!css || !IS_DOM) {
      return;
    }

    var style = DOCUMENT.createElement('style');
    style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
    style.innerHTML = css;
    var headChildren = DOCUMENT.head.childNodes;
    var beforeChild = null;

    for (var i = headChildren.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
      var child = headChildren[i];
      var tagName = (child.tagName || '').toUpperCase();

      if (['STYLE', 'LINK'].indexOf(tagName) > -1) {
        beforeChild = child;
      }
    }

    DOCUMENT.head.insertBefore(style, beforeChild);
    return css;
  }
```

Any idea on how to get this solved without adding unsafe-inline or hardcoded hash in the CSP?

Following is my webpack.config

```
    const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require('css-minimizer-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname  + '/src',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    entry: {
        app: './js/app.js',
        'app.min': './js/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../dist/bank',
        filename: './js/[name].js',
        publicPath: ''
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                include: /\.min\.js$/
            }),
            new CssMinimizerPlugin({
                include: /\.min\.css$/
            })
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './css/[name].css',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,  // Process css files
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,  // Process image files
                use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        esModule: false
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html)$/, // Process html files
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    },
};
```

Comment: Are you okay with a nonce?

Comment: From what I read in the internet, it seems hard coding the nonce is no safer than unsafe-inline. I want to see if there is a way I can import the stuff in webpack where 'self' would be sufficient.

Comment: If you hardcode and reuse a nonce, it's unsafe. What if you used a nonce properly, where it were different on every page load? Would you be okay with that?

Comment: I guess so, if there is no better option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was solved by removing the fontawesome js imports from the app.js. Apparently, only css files need to be imported and js files (i.e. fontawesome.js, regular.js and solid.js) are not required for the fonts to work.

By removing the js files, neither unsafe-inline, sha-XXX or nonce- is needed in the CSP.

Comment: Brilliant! This stopped literally thousands of CSP reports being sent when an icon was being hovered over too. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Webpack's documentation on Content Security Policies](https://webpack.js.org/guides/csp/), you can do this by setting `__webpack_nonce__` in your entry script (not your configuration file).

Comment: Thanks, but in the docs, it's not much information on how to set a nonce which is not a constant and how to update the CSP accordingly to accept that.